# Are there any quick setting floor leveling compounds?

Tags: floor

The self levelling compound under the vinyl floor tiles in our bathroom has started to break up so the tiles are now coming up.   We do not have another toilet so I need a solution that can be walked on quickly.

We are in the UK, and I am looking for something I can buy from a DIY shop or a builders merchant in the next day or so.  The concrete floor is not level and also has a few cracks, but nothing more than you expect in a 1930’s home.

Comment: If your leveling compound is cracking, then you likely have deflection in your floor or you mixed the compound improperly. Pouring a new compound isn't going to resole the deflection and it will just crack again.

Comment: @MatthewPK, I don't think the floor is moving.   The current compond was down when we brought our home, I expect it may have had two match water added to the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to say what will be available to you locally - so many products vary by location.

The product you are looking for is definitely out there.  The [first one](http://www.homedepot.ca/product/levelquik-rs-self-leveling-underlayment-227kg/921793) that came up in a search at HomeDepot Canada says it will setup for tiles in 4hrs and other floor coverings in 14hrs.

Ask around at your home renovation stores and building supply vendors to see what is available.

Comment: thanks I found http://www.wickes.co.uk/high-performance-levelling-compound-20kg/invt/154134/ that can be walked on in 1 or 2 hours